# How can I insert HTML data in iframe in React?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

How to insert "html" data in iframe ?

```
const Xcomponent = () => {

//$(iframe).contents().find('body').html( "<div> Hello </div>" )
    return (
    
{stateTheme.data && stateTheme.htmls.map( ( html, index)=> {
   return(<div> <iframe> </iframe> </div>)
})}

};
```

In static html I can insert with this code `$(iframe).contents().find('body').html( "<div> Hello </div>" )` , I am looking for same result here

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make a new component and do all the work there, inserting string html in react would seem strange when you have jsx

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).